# Go: Effects of empty curly braces on array initialisation memory allocation

Tags: arrays, memory-management, static, go, initialization

I was playing with different ways to initialise/declare arrays in golang. I got different behaviours/results.

*go version go1.3 darwin/amd64*

### version 1:

```
func main() {
    a := [100000000]int64{}
    var i int64
    for i = 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        a[i] = i
    }
}
```

Produces a 763MB binary. It crashes after a few seconds when I run it with this message.

*runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit*

*fatal error: stack overflow*

### version 2:

```
func main() {
    var a [100000000]int64
    var i int64
    for i = 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        a[i] = i
    }
}
```

Produces a 456KB binary. It runs in less than one second.

### Question:

Can anybody help me understand why those differences (and other I may have missed) are there? Thanks!

**edit:**

### Running times:

I built the two different snippets and run the compiled versions, so the compilation time wasn't added. The first time I run version1 is extremely slow in comparison though. Here is the output.

```
go build version1.go
go build version2.go
```

These are the execution outputs

#### version 1

**first run**

```
time ./version1
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x2fb42a8e)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:520 +0x69
runtime.newstack()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/stack.c:770 +0x486
runtime.morestack()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/asm_amd64.s:228 +0x61

goroutine 16 [stack growth]:
main.main()
    /Users/ec/repo/offers/lol/version1.go:3 fp=0x2b7b85f50 sp=0x2b7b85f48
runtime.main()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:247 +0x11a fp=0x2b7b85fa8 sp=0x2b7b85f50
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445 fp=0x2b7b85fb0 sp=0x2b7b85fa8
created by _rt0_go
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/asm_amd64.s:97 +0x120

goroutine 17 [runnable]:
runtime.MHeap_Scavenger()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/mheap.c:507
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445
./version1  0.00s user 0.10s system 1% cpu 7.799 total
```

**second run**

```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x2fb42a8e)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:520 +0x69
runtime.newstack()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/stack.c:770 +0x486
runtime.morestack()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/asm_amd64.s:228 +0x61

goroutine 16 [stack growth]:
main.main()
    /Users/ec/repo/offers/lol/version1.go:3 fp=0x2b7b85f50 sp=0x2b7b85f48
runtime.main()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:247 +0x11a fp=0x2b7b85fa8 sp=0x2b7b85f50
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445 fp=0x2b7b85fb0 sp=0x2b7b85fa8
created by _rt0_go
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/asm_amd64.s:97 +0x120

goroutine 17 [runnable]:
runtime.MHeap_Scavenger()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/mheap.c:507
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445
./version1  0.00s user 0.10s system 98% cpu 0.102 total
```

#### version 2

**first run**

```
time ./version2
./version2  0.16s user 0.26s system 99% cpu 0.429 total
```

**second run**

```
time ./version2
./version2  0.17s user 0.25s system 97% cpu 0.421 total
```

Comment: Note that both of these will *execute* very quickly. I assume you're testing with `go run`, and the time difference is in building the large binary.

Comment: Both *execute* quickly, but not for the first run of *version 1*. I built them in a previous step. I added more info in the original post.

Comment: @prok05 the reason the first time you run v1 it takes a while is because the OS is trying to cache the 700mb file in memory, the 2nd time the OS/filesystem already has it cached so it starts faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Version 1, you're declaring a literal array of `[100000000]int64{}` which the compiler immediately allocates.

Version 2, you're only declaring the *type* of `a` as `[100000000]int64`.

When you only have a variable declaration, the contents aren't known at that point during compilation. In version 2, the compiler knows that `a` is of type `[100000000]int64`, but the memory isn't allocated until runtime.

When you use a *literal*, that exact memory representation is written into the binary. It works the same as if you declared a `string` literal vs a variable of type `string`; the string literal will be written in place, while a variable declaration is only a placeholder.

Even though the current compiler (go 1.3) allows `a` to escape to the heap, the literal data is expected to live in the stack frame. You can see this in the assembly output (frame size is 800000016):

```
TEXT    "".func1+0(SB),$800000016-0
```

If you actually need a larger literal than what can fit in the stack, you can place it in a global variable. The following executes just fine:

```
var a = [100000000]int64{1}

func func1() {
    var i int64
    for i = 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        a[i] = i
    }
}
```

I did have to initialize at least one value in `a` here, because it seems that the compiler can elide this literal, if it's equal to the zero value.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't really explain what happens, does it (apart the size of the binary) ?

Comment: What do you mean it's only a placeholder ? The array is allocated and filled.

Comment: @dystroy: I mean that it's not preallocated (obviously, since the binary is <500KB), and the memory is allocated at runtime. That explains the binary size, but I'm not certain why version 1 has the stack overflow, since the compiler does escape `a` to the heap.

Comment: @dystroy version 1 gets stored in the binary and the runtime tries to use it on the stack which caused the overflow, version 2 gets allocated on the heap. I could be wrong, imo that should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @OneOfOne: I mediately expected a stack-overflow looking at the code, but wasn't sure why when I saw `a` escape (though escape analysis sin't something you should have to take into account when reasoning about your code).  It could be worth bringing up an issue, but I'm not sure of the implications of moving a literal out of the stack during compilation.

Comment: "but it doesn't need to set aside that memory until you initialize it in some way." It *is* initialized. Declaring a variable without an explicit initialization, implicitly initializes it to the type's *zero value*, which for arrays is having all elements initialized to the zero value, which should be identical to initializing it to a literal with empty braces. There are never "uninitialized variables".

Comment: @newacct: yes, I was trying to differentiate literal which is "allocated" during compilation, and a variable declaration which is allocated at runtime. Let me try to clean up the wording...

Comment: When there are curly braces, you might be initializing to a value other than zero (you can say `a := [2]int{1,2}`), which I suspect prompts Go to store the whole value you're initializing to in the binary (which usually works; most literals aren't huge). When there are no braces, the compiler "knows" it can just run code to zero-fill memory, so it doesn't store anything in the binary.

Comment: @twotwotwo: So the compiler is just not smart enough.

Comment: Yeah--it just sees you're using a *syntax* that initializes with a constant value so it stores the value; it doesn't "realize" that your value happens to be zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually an answer but maybe someone can find this useful.

In my case this happens when I've try to json.Marshal following structure:

```
type Element struct {
    Parent *Element
    Child []*Element
}
```

Where Parent points to element which has current element in Child.

So I just mark "Parent" as `json:"-"` to be ignored in marshalling.

Comment: That actually got me out of a reference cycle, thanks! Exactly what I needed.